# Sort based on alpha value instead of primary key

Tags: ms-access-2010

[image: example image]

The attached image is meant to represent an ongoing issue I am having with a database.
I use the primary key field in a couple of query and reports.  The issue I keep running into is that I cannot sort the aforementioned query and reports alphabetically using the linked field.  As the linked field is the field where the company’s name is it makes more sense to the end user for the reports to be alphabetical as opposed to being sorted based on the primary key number.
So to use the example above I cannot sort the report so that Bob’s company comes after BBB Company because Bob’s company was put into the data base at a later date than Sally’s company.  This is a real problem.

It is not practically to renumber each company’s primary keys because new companies will keep being inserted into the database and that would require renumbering all the entries every time there is a new entry.

Currently I export to excel, sort based on the name and then go from there.  I would really like to eliminate that export to excel though. Sorting at the report or query level does not eliminate the problem.  Thanks

Comment: Sorting in the query should never be done. Sorting in the report will work.

Comment: I'm afraid that sorting in the report does not work in this instance.  Tried that and the sort still goes by the primary key number as opposed to the alpha.

Comment: That can't be so. Double-check the sort settings in the report.

Comment: I have double checked/worked with the settings an the issue persists.  Given the responses I'm getting I can only conclude I am not giving enough information to get the assistance I require.  Initially I thought this was a simple sorting issue but after dealing with it for a length of time there is something going on.  My suspicion is with the fields in the database and how they are linked via relationships/ database table design. Thanks for your assistance, I understand what is being put forward about sorting, but it is not solving the issue.

Comment: Yes, something else must be going on.

Answer (score 0):

Sort the data in report only. Open report in layout view [image: select Group and sort option] . You can also apply group functionality irrespective of your query.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but it does not accomplish the goal.  The sort still produces an end result where the primary key is the mechanism the program uses to sort.

Comment: This should not be done . You are doing something wrong I guess !